# Download button in app

Tags: iphone

Has anyone seen iPad greeting cards app... what they have done is released the app with some limited greeting cards and now user can download the other cards from web by paying some amt.... I want to implement such functionality .. has anyone any idead about that.. I know that can be implemented by taking image from url recieved data and saving that image in app.... but i dnt know how i will establish connection between app and web that paricular user has paid the amount and so now card can be downladed into his app and also where will that card be saved whether in userbundle or somewhere else...please give me some direction....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are wanting is "in-app purchases".

See:
http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/inapppurchase/

By adding in-app purchases to your app you will be able to sell additional functionality to your users from directly within your app.

Comment: wow..this forum has never sent me empty handed.. thanks to members like u .. always helpful ... thanks a lot... +1 for ur answer